# Como identificar corretamente os clusters utilizando kmeans?

Tags: r, aprendizagem-de-máquina, k-means

Suponhamos que eu deseje classificar os espécimes do conjunto de dados iris utilizando o método k-means. Além disso, quero avaliar se a classificação foi boa ou não. A maneira mais fácil de fazer isto é a seguinte:

```
iris.kmeans <- kmeans(iris[, 1:4], 3)
table(iris$Species, iris.kmeans$cluster)

              1  2  3
  setosa     17 33  0
  versicolor  4  0 46
  virginica   0  0 50
```

Entretanto, não sei identificar se os resultados estão bons ou não. Aparentemente, a classe 3 equivale à espécie virginica, a classe 2 corresponde à setosa e a classe 1 corresponde à versicolor. Minhas perguntas são:

1) Como posso ter certeza se a minha afirmação acima está correta? Como ter certeza de que o k-means não está classificando os espécimes de maneira muito errada?

2) Existe alguma forma automatizada da minha tabela possuir os nomes das espécies nas linhas e colunas, em vez de apenas nas linhas?

3) Há alguma função de algum outro pacote do R que seja melhor do que a função kmeans original do R?

Comment: Olhe a ajuda da função `clusterboot`  do pacote `fpc`.

Comment: Sobre a pergunta 3, algum classificador supervisionado vai ser mesmo melhor do que o k-médias para esse problema, como o colega @DanielFalbel já bem explicou na resposta dele. Eu não sou muito conhecedor de R, mas se vc puder usar Python dá uma olhada no Scikitlearn: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_iris.html

Comment: Para funções de SVM tem o pacote `kernlab`

Comment: Sim, estou ciente disso. E conheço o pacote `caret` também. Mas não estou procurando um classificador deste tipo. Estou interessado no kmeans e nas suas limitações.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Meu primeiro pensamento é que o `kmeans` não é um método de classificação e sim um método de clusterização. A diferença é sutil, mas bastante importante.

O `kmeans` é um método não supervisionado. Não tem nada neste algoritmo que está forçando que os grupos criados sejam parecidos com os grupos das espécies de plantas (neste exemplo).

Por ser um método não supervisionado, é difícil dizer também qual é o melhor cluster possível... Torna-se um problema um pouco subjetivo. O que pode ser usado é:

1. a soma das variâncias intragrupo: se dentro de cada grupo for muito grande, quer dizer que o seu cluster não está muito bom
2. tem também o [Rand Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_index) que está implementado neste pacote `fpc` que o Robert falou nos comentários

Enfim, respondendo as suas perguntas:

1. Ele está classificando de forma muito errada, basta você observar que os individuos de classe `setosa` estão dividios em dois clusters: 1 e 2. E o cluster 3 contém indivíduos tanto da classe `versicolor` quanto `virginica`. Ou seja o cluster não está ajudando a separar as classes de plantas.
2. Desconheço, mas a princípio, você poderia falar que cada o label de cada cluster, é aquele da classe que aparece mais naquele cluster...
3. Não sei responder.

Para mim, no seu caso faria mais sentido usar um algoritmo de aprendizado supervisionado como `random forest`, `regressão logística`, `knn` e etc.

---

Para ilustrar o problema de usar o `kmeans` considere o seguinte banco de dados:

```
dados <- data_frame(
  x = runif(10000), y = runif(10000), 
  grupo = ifelse(x > 0.25 & x < 0.75 & y > 0.25 & y < 0.75, "azul", "vermelho")
  )
```

Veja que o grupo é determinísticamente criado a partir de `x` e `y`. Não existe aleatoriedade.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora rode um cluster `kmeans` nessa base e vamos ver se os grupos ficam parecidos.

```
cluster <- kmeans(dados[,1:2], 2)
table(cluster$cluster, dados$grupo)


    azul vermelho
  1 1263     3670
  2 1273     3794
```

Não ficaram, porque em nenhum momento eu pedi para o `kmeans` separar os dois grupos. Ele separou apenas de acordo com os valores de `x` e `y` que eram próximos...

Veja no gráfico como ficaram os grupos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora vamos ajustar um random forest nesses dados:

```
dados$grupo <- as.factor(dados$grupo)
rf <- randomForest::randomForest(grupo ~ x + y, data = dados)
table(predict(rf, dados), dados$grupo)


           azul vermelho
  azul     2536        0
  vermelho    0     7464
```

Agora sim! COnseguimos acertar tudo que era azul e o que era vermelho. Isso acontece porque estamos supervisionando o `random forest`, ou seja estamos oferecendo classificações para que o algoritmo aprenda.

Comment: "Meu primeiro pensamento é que o kmeans não é um método de classificação e sim um método de clusterização. A diferença é sutil, mas bastante importante." Nem terminei de ler, mas já ganhou meu +1. :)

Comment: Realmente, valeu o +1. Ótima resposta. :)

Comment: Eu já sabia das limitações do kmeans, principalmente por ele ser um classificador (ou clusterizador) linear, mas o teu exemplo foi excelente e bastante ilustrativo. Obrigado.